# How to pack a IP address represented as a string, into a unsigned long

Tags: c++, string, c++11, type-conversion

How to pack an IP address, represented with a string, into an `unsigned long`. Please give solutions in C++ in a more efficient way (and with less code).
Thanks in advance!!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>

    int main()
    {
        unsigned long Id1;
        std::string item = "1.2.3.4";
        Id1 = ??(here item need to be packed in Id1)
        std::cout << Id1 <<std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: That's the right output for the code you wrote. What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: do excpect to get 10! ? dealing with "." as multiple operation ?

Comment: @pete Becker : i need the entire string. Thanks

Comment: A `long` stores a numeric value. There's no obvious way to interpret "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10" as a numeric value.

Comment: @Pete Becker: please see my below clarification for mathew..which states my requirement. Thanks

Comment: No, I'm not going to hunt through your comments to answers to try to find your requirements. Put them in the question!

Comment: Wow guys the question is exceedingly clear. http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton

Comment: @Joshua: When the question was closed, it was complete nonsense. Not only did it not say anything about IP addresses, but given the string format, it could not possibly have been about IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear because your string contains decimal points and a `signed long` is integral.

Also, if we take the `'.'` character as a separator, this means that there are 10 numbers in the string not one.

If you want to copy the characters in the string to the memory occupied by a `signed long`, you could try something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  signed long value = 0;
  const std::string item = "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10";
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(signed long); ++i)
  {
    // shift left one byte to make room for the next character
    value = value * 256; 

    // Insert the character from the string.
    value += string[i];
  }
```

Another method is to use `memcpy`:

```
  memcpy(&value, item.c_str(), sizeof(signed long));
```

**Edit 1: Copying into a `slong`**
Using the above example, the '.' characters are skipped:

```
int main(void)
{
  slong value = 0;
  const unsigned int destination_capacity = sizeof(slong);
  const std::string item = "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10";
  const unsigned int length = item.size();
  unsigned int chars_copied = 0U;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
    const char c = item[i];
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
      // shift left one byte to make room for the next character
      value = value * 256; 

      // Insert the character from the string.
      value += string[i];
      chars_copied++;
      if (chars_copied >= destination_capacity)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

The above copies the digit characters from the string and packs them into a `slong` type.

Comment: as per a requirement, the variable type used to store the above type of string is mentioned as slong in hardware headers files. so iam trying to pack the structure manually as sent by hardware and execute a application. So the need here is how to send the above dot seperated values using slong?? Thanks Feel free to ask more clarification

Comment: for example :"167840383"  represents "10.1.10.127"

Comment: @Ragav: that's an entirely different conversion! Describe the exact rule `string` -> `slong`, as it's not obvious how to decipher the algorithm given your example.

Comment: @Ragav - presumably, `if (item == "10.1.10.127") value = 167840383; else value = 0;` is not acceptable. But that's all the detailed information that you've provided. If you want something else you'll have to say **exactly what it is** that you want.

Comment: @Ragav: There are library packages out there for converting IP and MAC addresses from a string and placing them into a buffer.  You need to search for "C++ IP string to buffer"

Comment: @Ragav: IP and MAC addresses only have 3 periods, '.', not 9.

Comment: Hint:  View the `slong` variable in hexadecimal, not decimal.  Split the hexadecimal variable into groups of 2 digits.  Convert each pair to decimal.  Place '.' between the decimal numbers.  You should have your IP address from a `slong` type.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews since you've been able to find out the assignment here, I've posted an answer below attempting to solve it with stdlib, take a look if you wish.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews in your solution, only single digits are accepted, while for IP's you need 1 to 3 digits. But you didn't know the task when typing the solution, OTOH.

Comment: @iksemyonov: My solution is not a good solution for processing MAC and IP addresses because it does not convert the textual representation into a numerical representation.  The solution only copies or packs the ASCII digit characters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews well the problem here is that the OP seems to not really know what they're looking for in the solution anyway. What would you say about my approach though?

Answer (score 1):

`atol` sees digits through until a nondigit appears

entire string is not digit, entire string you will see from this code

```
int main()
{
    long Id1;
    std::string item = "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10";
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

**UPD:**

I suggest my effective and universal algoithm:

Params:

```
str - string to parse
sep - fiels separator, which delimit digit position 
textbase - radix of digits in text string
fieldbase - field radix of position in target number
```

see about radix here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system

```
template<typename T>
T str2num( const std::string &str, char sep, int textbase, int fieldbase ) {
  T digit, result = 0;
  std::size_t pos=0, start = 0, end = str.size() - 1;
  std::string strnum;
  while( ( start = str.rfind(sep,end) ) != std::string::npos ) {
    strnum = str.substr( start + 1, end - start );
    digit = std::strtol( strnum.c_str(), 0, textbase );
    result += digit * pow( fieldbase, pos );
    end = start - 1;
    ++pos;
  }
  strnum = str.substr( 0, end + ( start ? 1 : 0 ) );
  digit = std::strtol( strnum.c_str(), 0, textbase );
  result += digit * pow( fieldbase, pos );
  return result;
}
```

So this universal function may be used for any analogical purpose. For example parse and convert IP adresses from string into binary form. Currently it is simple for IPv4. But IPv6 will be simple later when compilers will be support 128 bit width integer values. But currenlly IPv6 possible to parse with split string to two substrings with four fields.

There is an example how to use:

```
int main()
{
  typedef unsigned long ul32;
  typedef unsigned long long ul64;

  // parse the IPv4 adress, where numerical system of digits
  // in fields id 10, and field radix is 256 (in hex 0x100)
  ul32 x32 = str2num<ul32>( "10.1.10.127", '.', 10, 256 );
  std::cout << x32 << std::endl;

  // parse half of the IPv6 adress, where numerical system of digits
  // in fields id 16, and field radix is 65536 (in hex 0x10000)
  ul64 x64 = str2num<ul64>( "1234:5678:9abc:def0", ':', 16, 65536 );
  std::cout << std::hex << x64 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The result output:

```
167840383
123456789abcdef0
```

PS:

When You will try to compile this with 64 bit integers, the standart library pow() function is not support 64 bit values, so need to use special implementation of pow. For example Indian pow algorithm. I found pascal implementation here: http://www.algolib.narod.ru/Math/IndianPow.html So make translate to c++:

```
template<typename T>
T pow( T base, unsigned int exp ) {
  T t = base, res = 1;
  while( 1 ) {
    if ( exp & 1 ) res *= t;
    exp >>= 1;
    if ( ! exp ) return res;
    t *= t;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You How can i store the above string to the slong?

Comment: @Ragav: Is it not obvious to you by now that you can't?

Comment: What is the reason to devote? Man ask result in comments "i need the entire string". The aswer is exactly is. The reason that it is impossible writed. Such answer as question.

Comment: @oklas : i cant devote.. because iam a new user here.. aorry i dont know who did..

Answer (score 0):

Edited: it's not about stripping the dots, it's about packing 4 fields into one `unsigned long`. Here's my take on it with the standard library:

Edited once more: Using the safe `stoi()` now, with a wrapper. (Pity we don't have Erlang-like tuple return types with pattern matching.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

std::pair<bool, int> stoi_wrap(const std::string& s)
{
    std::pair<bool, int> res(true, 0);
    try {
        res.second = std::stoi(s);
    } catch (std::exception e) {
        res.first = false;
    }
    return res;
}    

int main(int agrc, char **argv)
{
    std::string s = "10.1.10.127";
    std::vector<unsigned char> fields;
    std::stringstream stream(s); std::string temp;
    while(std::getline(stream, temp, '.')) {
       const auto res = stoi_wrap(temp);
       if (!res.first) {
           std::cerr << "error reading a field" << '\n'; return -1;
       }
       else
           fields.push_back(res.second);
    }
    if (fields.size() != 4) {
        std::cerr << "wrong field count" << std::endl; return -1;
    }
    unsigned long int result{}; int i{};
    for (auto it = fields.rbegin(); it != fields.rend(); it++) {
        result += *it << 8*i; ++i;
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!! any minimized code in c++ version..

Comment: "any minimized code" what do you mean exactly? All the code above is required to perform the operation. You can split it into a function, for example.

Comment: ok.. in c++ we can use some STL's and can we make the similar goal achieved? Just curious to know that...

Comment: Do you want to perfrom this task with a single calls to an STL function? I'm afraid it's not possible.

Comment: Welcome to post any other way in c++?

Comment: What do you dislike about this way?

Comment: Sorry i didnt "dislike".. my need is to incorporate the solution in c++..

Comment: Yes this is pure C++ language! Go ahead and use it.

Comment: One doubt is do we need more logic and code to store a ip address to a variable.. in c++.

Comment: There is pretty much one solution: go forward and test it.. I've included a couple checks in this code, you may add more, it's just one approach shown here.
Once again: what do you dislike about this approach? Too little code? Too much?

Comment: i dont know if this is the only way.. but i need less code with some library calls etc.. in c++.. Appreciate your effort!!

Comment: Why do you need less code? My code is making library calls, lots of.